# java - Create a filled in grid with a 2D array of Booleans

Tags: java, jframe, jtable

I have a program that processes some data and creates a 2D array of Booleans. After processing, I want a grid displayed with the resulting array (filled in where true, empty if null or false). How can I do this with a JFrame (and maybe a JTable). All the examples I keep seeing create a grid that get filled in by clicking and I just need a visual display of a premade array. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Maybe a simple function to pass a 2D array to that would pop up the grid?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @MikeWeber Perhaps instead of relying on Gildraths google skills you should have researched the problem further, maybe something like [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) would have been a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that could work:
Inspired by: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/a-simple-jtable-example-for-display

```
public class TableExample extends JFrame{
    public TableExample()
    {
        //headers for the table
        String[] columns = new String[] {
            "Field", "Boolean Value1", "Boolean Value2"
        };

        //actual data for the table in a 2d array
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
            {"Check YX", false, false },
            {"Check XZ", true, true },
        };

        //create table with data
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);

        //add the table to the frame
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        this.setTitle("Table Example");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableExample();
            }
        });
    }   
}
```